# join() returns a list instead of a string

Tags: python, string

I am doing the codewars 'Replace With Alphabet Position' fundamental training challenge. I have pretty much got the desired result, but now the problem is that my return statement is returning the result in a list (`[]`) rather than the string itself.

I found this tutorial that said to use the join method (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join), but when I try that.. it is not giving me just the joined values.

These are the instructions:

> Welcome.
>
> In this kata you are required to, given a string, replace every letter
>   with its position in the alphabet.
>
> If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it.
>
> "a" = 1, "b" = 2, etc.
>
> Example
>
> alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
>
> Should return "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5
>   15 3 12 15 3 11" (as a string)

Here's my code:

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    text = text.lower()
    print(text)
    alphabet = {
        'a':1,
        'b':2,
        'c':3,
        'd':4,
        'e':5,
        'f':6,
        'g':7,
        'h':8,
        'i':9,
        'j':10,
        'k':11,
        'l':12,
        'm':13,
        'n':14,
        'o':15,
        'p':16,
        'q':17,
        'r':18,
        's':19,
        't':20,
        'u':21,
        'v':22,
        'w':23,
        'x':24,
        'y':25,
        'z':26
    }

    new_string = []

    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            new_string.append(alphabet.get(char))
    return ''.join(str(new_string))
```

Here is the output:

```
Time: 801ms Passed: 0 Failed: 3 Exit Code: 1
Test Results:
Log
the sunset sets at twelve o' clock.
'[20, 8, 5, 19, 21, 14, 19, 5, 20, 19, 5, 20, 19, 1, 20, 20, 23, 5, 12, 22, 5, 15, 3, 12, 15, 3, 11]' should equal '20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11'
Log
the narwhal bacons at midnight.
'[20, 8, 5, 14, 1, 18, 23, 8, 1, 12, 2, 1, 3, 15, 14, 19, 1, 20, 13, 9, 4, 14, 9, 7, 8, 20]' should equal '20 8 5 14 1 18 23 8 1 12 2 1 3 15 14 19 1 20 13 9 4 14 9 7 8 20'
Log
6479121244
'[]' should equal ''
```

Comment: Why are you calling `str`?

Comment: @user2357112 if I do not call str() then it gives me a console error: 

 STDERR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."), "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11")
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 38, in alphabet_position
    return ''.join(new_string)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: That's because each element in `new_string` is an int. Try

`return ' '.join( str(x) for x in new_string )`

Comment: Your alphabet dictionary should have string values, not ints.

Comment: use `str(new_string)` without `join()` and you see the same text with `[20, 8, ..]`. Your problem is that you have list with integers and you have to convert every number to string separatelly like `[str(x) for x in new_string]` and then you have list with strings and you can use `join()`. You can also convert every integer to string using `str()` when you apppend it `new_string.append( str(alphabet.get(char)) )`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.join()` expects a list of strings, but `alphabet.get(char)` returns an `int` so `new_string` is a list of `int`s. You need to move the call to `str()` into the previous line, like so:

```
for char in text:
    if char.isalpha():
        new_string.append(str(alphabet.get(char)))
return ''.join(new_string)
```

Comment: the problem is still with converting the whole list to a string with `str(new_string)` so `join` gets a string not a list

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo! I forgot to modify the final line. Seat of the pants kinda phone coding :) Have updated the code.